# Replacing a class method in objective C and calling original implementation

Tags: objective-c, introspection, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to replace a class method of UIImage with my own implementation.

In some cases, my implementation might just want to call the original UIImage implementation.

Here is my code

```
#import "UIImage+SkinnedImage.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIImage (SkinnedImagePrivate)

+ (UIImage *)originalImageNamed:(NSString*)name;

@end


@implementation UIImage (SkinnedImage)

+ (void)allowSkinning {
    Method imageNamedMethod = class_getClassMethod([UIImage class], @selector(imageNamed:));
    IMP originalImageNamedIMP = class_getMethodImplementation_stret([UIImage class], @selector(imageNamed:));
    Method swizzled = class_getClassMethod([UIImage class], @selector(skinnedImageNamed:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(imageNamedMethod, swizzled);
    const char *signatureEnconding = method_getTypeEncoding(imageNamedMethod);
    class_addMethod([UIImage class], @selector(originalImageNamed:), originalImageNamedIMP, signatureEnconding);

}


+ (UIImage *)skinnedImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    //XXX 
    return [UIImage originalImageNamed:name];
}

@end
```

1. `+ (void)allowSkinning` is called.
2. `+ (UIImage *)skinnedImageNamed:(NSString *)name` is called instead of `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name;`
3. `return [UIImage originalImageNamed:name];` crash with error:

> reason: '+[UIImage originalImageNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class

Why did  class_addMethod([UIImage class], @selector(originalImageNamed:), originalImageNamedIMP, signatureEnconding); failed to provide me with an implementation ?

Please note that the function class_addMethod returns true

Comment: add the `-ObjC` flag in the build settings under `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: @Wongzigii I already had it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line adds an instance method, `-originalImageNamed:`, to `UIImage`:

```
class_addMethod([UIImage class], @selector(originalImageNamed:), originalImageNamedIMP, signatureEnconding);
```

You can change it to:

```
class_addMethod(object_getClass([UIImage class]), @selector(originalImageNamed:), originalImageNamedIMP, signatureEnconding);
```

Or, equivalently:

```
class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass("UIImage"), @selector(originalImageNamed:), originalImageNamedIMP, signatureEnconding);
```

A class method is an instance method on the class's meta-class. So, adding an instance method to that meta-class adds a class method to the class.

There's a similar problem with your call to `class_getMethodImplementation_stret()`. That function gets the implementation of an instance method. Therefore, if you want to get a class method, you have to pass the class's meta-class:

```
IMP originalImageNamedIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(object_getClass([UIImage class]), @selector(imageNamed:));
```

Or, since you already have the corresponding `Method`, you could do:

```
IMP originalImageNamedIMP = method_getImplementation(imageNamedMethod);
```

By the way, why are you using `class_getMethodImplementation_stret()`? `+imageNamed:` does not return a structure.

Comment: I tried with `both objc_getMetaClass("UIImage")` and  `object_getClass([UIImage class])`, and with _stret and without (documentation is not very clear on the difference between the two)

However, the app still crash in the same way when I try to call originalImageNamed...

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have a similar problem in getting the original implementation.